# keras how to add a Lambda layer to round the value of a tensor to 0 or 1

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to use a Lambda layer as the last layer to round the output from the sigmoid activation to either 0 or 1.

But it seems like I cannot just write the code like this:

```
X = Lambda(lambda x: K.round(x))(X_output)
```

it will return a non derivative error.

How can I modify it to de a derivative rounding to 0 or 1?

Comment: Are you training a classifier or regressor?

Comment: I'm training a regressor and use mae loss

Answer (score 1):

You could consider training the model without `round` like

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(32, input_shape=(5,)))
model.add(Dense(1, activation="sigmoid"))
#model.add(Lambda(lambda x: K.round(x)))

model.compile("adam", "mae") # or cross entropy
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

model.save_weights("/path/to/model.h5")
```

Add `round` now.

```
output = Lambda(lambda x: K.round(x)) (model.output)
m1 = Model(model.input, output)
m1.load_weights("/path/to/model.h5")
```

Comment: but I'd like it to train with rounded results

Comment: the model will not be able to learn if 0.75 is better than 0.6 when it is discrete.

Comment: Couldn't you add a penalty to the loss if number is not an "int" (ex, 2.4 would get 0.4 penalty, 5.9 would get 0.1 penalty etc.)?